# IR2110 and Vcc Vdd COM relationship

Tags: mosfet-driver

I am using the IR2110 [IR2110 datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2110-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c80333167e) to drive a full bridge.
The datasheet says that Vss ( logic ground ) may be up to 25V less than the voltage that powers the driving side Vcc.
In my case I need to have Vss -25V.
The full bridge did work when the grounds between logic and driving side where connected between them.

But when I change that it does not work.

So I got a single IR2110 to test it.
I connected 0V to Vss. 5V to Vdd.
10V to COM and 22V to Vcc.
If you want to see the voltages differently, say: -10 to Vdd, -5 to Vss. 0 to COM and 12V to Vcc.
I connected also the Lin to and Arduino (connecting logic ground) and put SD to logic ground.

Result: The chip "exploded" and a hole exists in it! It is also dangerous because may injure the eyes!

What am I not understanding?

[image: exploded ir2110]

Comment: Please link to the data sheet so we don’t have to search the interweb for it. Maybe the 25 V is absolute maximum rating and not within its suitable supply range?

Comment: Show your circuit.

Comment: 25V sounds like way too much. You must have misunderstood the datasheet

Comment: Page 2 of the datasheet at the first table line 7 states: Vss between Vcc-25 Vcc+0.3 .

Comment: that is not what that means

Comment: Your re-stotement has VDD < VSS which won't do the chip any good at all.

Comment: It seems to me that the connections made by @George Kourtis do not violate the recommended (or absolute maximum) values, but a complete schematic would be helpful. I found an application note with configurations for half-bridge as well as high side and low side drive. The author also warns against using devices purchased from Pakistan, and says that the almost identical IR2112 worked "perfectly". https://microcontrollerslab.com/mosfet-driver-ir2110-pinout-examples-applications-datasheet/

Answer (score 1):

"All voltage parameters are absolute voltages referenced to COM."
VSS and COM should have the same voltage level. I think they are separated but only for small signals and can not withstand a higher DC voltage. I may be wrong, but I think is something like in this picture with 2 antiparallel diodes.

[image]

Comment: If it says that VSS and COM may have different voltages I suppose the datasheet means it !

Comment: In datasheet even the dynamic and static characteristics are specified under  "VSS = COM unless otherwise specified" condition

Comment: When you order another IC please use a multimeter in diode mode and check this.

Comment: I checked the connection between Vss and Vcc and it seems current may flow from Vss to Vcc through a diode ( the reverse path is blocked ) - new chip obviously

Comment: Diode mode, and with another IC. You said that the chip "exploded" and it's a hole in it. You can rely on it. Now those diodes are gone. Or at least one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the recommended operating conditions, not the absolute maximum ratings.

When it says Vcc, Vss, Vdd, etc. in the "Absolute Max Rating" table, it does not mean the actual value being used. It means the worst case value in that same table. They are constants in that table, not variables.

So when you insert actual values being used into expressions in the "Absolute Max Rating" table, you get nonsensical results.

This is unlike the the "Recommended Operating Conditions" table where they are variables for the actual values being used.

Comment: On page 4 shows the functional block diagram. On the left we have Vss and Vdd and on the right COM, Vcc. They are not related to each other. More over at page 2 it says that the recommened operating conditions are to have: Vss between -5V and +5V. I suppose that the voltages are referenced to COM.

Comment: "They are not related to each other." They are.. Read the table carefully. Vdd and Vcc are directly compared against COM. Vss is directly compared against Vcc so is compared against COM by proxy.

Comment: According to the above table it says that Vcc may be between 0 and +25V ( rounding ). I choose +12V. It says too that Vss may be between Vcc-25 and Vcc, thus in my case between -13V and 12V. I connected -10V.

Comment: You are reading those inequalities completely incorrectly.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, the table says that Vss minimum value is Vcc-25V and that the maximum value is roughly Vcc. Thus Vcc-25V=+12V-25V=-13V. What do I read uncorrectly ?

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem. Or part of it. Use recommended operating conditions, not absolute maximum ratings. I understand how you get what you get now. Let me think about it.

Comment: I know. When it says Vcc in the absolute max rating table, it does not mean the actual Vcc. It means the worst case Vcc in that same table

Comment: Indeed. When you have maximum VCC your minimum VSS should be VCC-25, and "All voltage parameters are absolute voltages referenced to COM" leads to VSS = COM